# How to make an Android application that will connect and read data from an alarm system (local network)?

Tags: android

I need to make an Android app for the problem mentioned in the title. This system already runs on Windows and is connected to the computer via an UTP cable. Now, I need to connect to the local network that I already did by connecting it to the router (I'm not sure if this is enough, but using the Fing app I detected the device in the local network), and build an Android app.
Just to mention I have tried NSD (link below) but I do not think the alarm system supports it.

https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html

I had a problem defining the type of service. I tried to find all the devices using the code below, but unsuccessfully.

private static final String SERVICE_TYPE = "_services._dns-sd._udp";

Using this type of service I could not find anything, i.e. I did not manage to trigger the method
public void onServiceFound (NsdServiceInfo service)

My question is, should I continue with this approach (is it possible at all)? Otherwise, I need some guidance on how to connect to the device and read data(string type). 
For now, I only have the IP address I received using the Fing app.

Comment: and what do you mean by "the device"? `avahi` might tell the admin URL.

Comment: Device is one grey closed box with one UTP which is used for communication with windows app (I don't know what kind of hardware is inside). Certain number of push button (micro switch) can be conected to device by wiring. When user press for some reason button, information (id, date, time...) is send to device. My job is to transfer information  further to local network, and to create android app to read that information from network, and display to end users. I dont know how to start. I connected device to my rooter and now I can see device IP address (Fing app).

Comment: you need to run this tool on a notebook; just plugin a cross-link cable, no router required/desired... then capture packets with [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org). else you'll never know the port and the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution for my problem. This is how to connect device and check are data is transferring (in case the someone have similar problem). 

You need to do next:

- connect device direct to yours computer with Ethernet cable
- used WireShark app to find ip address, port and protocol (utp
  protocol in     my case)
- after get device data,  disconect device and reconnect    directly with yours modem (no need for aditional device like ethernet switch, or to    do the port forwarding)
- you can use some udp    client app on android phone to check if data
  are receiving (I used    TCP Sender / Receiver). Just set ip address
  and    port.

My problem was  because I used wrong UDP client app. That's the reason it didn't working from the beginning.